# MySQL - loop through rows

Tags: mysql, sql, database, loops, rows

I have the following code

```
select count(*)
from (select Annotations.user_id
from Annotations, Users
where Users.gender =  'Female'
and Users.user_id = Annotations.user_id
and image_id = 1
group by Annotations.user_id
having sum(case when stem = 'taxi' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when stem = 'zebra crossing' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
) Annotations
```

It produces a count of how many females who have given the stem 'taxi' and 'zebra crossing' for image 1.

Sample data

```
 user id, image id, stem
 1           1      image
 1           1      taxi
 1           1      zebra crossing
 2           1      person
 2           1      zebra crossing
 2           1      taxi
 3           1      person
 3           1      zebra crossing
```

Expected result (or similar)

```
stem1,  stem2,            count
taxi ,  zebra crossing      2
person, zebra crossing      2
```

However, as there are over 2000 stems, I cannot specify them all.

How would I go around looping through the stem rows with the image_id = 1 and gender = female as opposed to specifying the stem string?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please post your sample data and the expected result?

Comment: What table does `stem` belong to?

Comment: @PM77-1 77-1  edited for the sample data
and stem belongs to the annotations table

Comment: Do you need a count of **any two** of the stems?  Did I get it right?

Comment: @PM77-1 yeah a count of any 2 stems.  So if I had another entry by user id 4, with image/ taxi, then the count would be 2, as user id 1 too has these stems

Comment: Posted my code. I have not tested it - just tried on your sample data. So it could be half-baked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my attempt to solve your problem:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Count, a1.stem AS Stem1, a2.Stem AS Stem2 
FROM Annotations AS a1
INNER JOIN Annotations AS a2 ON a1.user_id = a2.user_id AND a1.image_id = a2.image_id
                          AND a1.stem < a2.stem 
WHERE a1.image_id = 1
GROUP BY a1.stem, a2.Stem
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

I did not include `image_id` logic.

Please see my SQL Fiddle here:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4ee69/33

Based on the following data (copied from yours) I get the result posted underneath it.

```
CREATE TABLE Annotations
    (`user_id` int, `image_id` int, `stem` varchar(14))
;

INSERT INTO Annotations
    (`user_id`, `image_id`, `stem`)
VALUES
    (1, 1, 'image'),
    (1, 1, 'taxi'),
    (1, 1, 'zebra crossing'),
    (2, 1, 'person'),
    (2, 1, 'zebra crossing'),
    (2, 1, 'taxi'),
    (3, 1, 'person'),
    (3, 1, 'zebra crossing')
;
```

```
  COUNT STEM1   STEM2
    2   person  zebra crossing
    2   taxi    zebra crossing
```

Comment: this provides me with a column of stem 1 with entries of letter a for some reason :S  would this be down to the fact that I haven't specified the image_id?  How would you I specify the image_id within your code?

Comment: Unless you have various image_id values in your data my omittion shouldn't matter.

Comment: I have 5 image_ids and would like to query them separately

Comment: Please check my demo (link in the post).  If it performs alright I'll update for `image_id`.  I do not have access to MySql server, so SQLFiddle.com is my only playground.

Comment: It performs correctly.  But now I need to specify image_id=1 and user.gender=female.  How would I add this into your code so I can see if it works on my actual db

Comment: I have posted code with `image_id` logic.  New link to SQL Fiddle as well.

Comment: This works perfectly!  Thank you.  One last question.  If I needed to incorporate gender (connected to the Users table by their user_id) how would I do so?

Comment: This fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/64ca4/1 has "female" logic as well. I have not posted it into the answer yet.

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:** As I understand it, you want to select all combinations of 2 stems, and get a count of how many users have that combination of stems. Here is my solution:

```
SELECT stem1, stem2, count(*) as count FROM
(
    SELECT a.user_id,a.image_id,a.stem as stem1,b.stem as stem2
    FROM Annotations a JOIN Annotations b
    ON a.user_id=b.user_id && b.image_id=a.image_id && a.stem!=b.stem
    JOIN Users ON Users.user_id = a.user_id
    WHERE Users.gender = "Female"
) as stems GROUP BY stem1, stem2 having count > 1 WHERE image_id=1;
```

The caveat here is that it will return 2 rows for each combinations of stems. (The second occurrence will have the stems in reverse order).

Comment: I like what this produces.  However, the count I'm slightly confused about.  Does it count how many users have named the same group_concat?

Comment: this counts how many stem each user has given not their co-occurrence

Comment: I've updated my answer. This will now produce a list showing combinations of 2 stems, and how many users have each combination.

Answer (score 1):

<strike>As per my understanding, you need to fetch female users that have `2 or more stems`</strike>

**Update:** It seems you need to display the user's that have a stem that is used by another user too, I have updated the query for the same

```
 SELECT
    distinct a.user_id,
    group_concat(DISTINCT a.stem ORDER BY a.stem)
 FROM
    Annotations a 
    JOIN Users u ON ( a.user_id = u.user_id AND u.gender =  'Female' )
    JOIN 
        (
            SELECT 
                b.user_id,
                b.stem
            FROM
                Annotations b
        ) AS b ON ( a.user_id <> b.user_id AND b.stem = a.stem )
 WHERE
    a.image_id = 1
GROUP BY
  a.user_id
```

Comment: It gives a count of total stems of a particular user

Comment: Ok, also it seems that your requirment is different, of getting users that have stems, where the stem of a particular user is also used by some other user, right?

Comment: Also, I'm afraid your understanding is incorrect.  I'm **not** looking for to fetch female users that have 2 or more stems.  I'm looking to do exactly as my example shows, and find occurrences of two stems together.

Comment: @user2233286 I have updated the answer, please let me know if its helpful

Comment: again this does not produce what I need, as there is no count.  I cannot explain it any better than my original question.  Other than:
You and I have 3 stems each, and we're both female.  2/3 stems each are the same.  Therefore that count is 2.  I want to display the stems along with its count.  If we add another user who also has the same attributes.  Therefore the count is 3.  However if your second and third stem is the same as their second and third stem, that count is 2.  I hope this clearly explains to you what I'm trying to do

Comment: I do not need to display a user.

Comment: oh k, what if 2 users have 3 stems out of which only 1 is common, you ignore this right? You just need 2 or more stems that are common among 2 or more users, right?

Comment: that's correct :) the only reason I ignore 1 common stem is because I have counted their frequencies already

Comment: Ok, In the demo data you provided, "person, zebra crossing" the count of this should be 2 right instead of 1, as "person, zebra crossing" are presnt for user_id 2 and 3

Comment: do you think you can help? :)

Comment: @user2233286 sorry, felt asleep (as it was 1a.m here), nice to know your query was resolved